# How do I join two tables by string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join two tables on the basis of a string of IDs.
This is my query so far.

```
SELECT sc.size_id from subcategories s 
join categories c on c.id = s.categories_id 
join size_categories sc on sc.categories_id = c.id ;
```

The result is

```
size_id 
1,2,5       
1,2,5   
4,2,1   
4,2,1   
1,2,5   
1,2,5       
4,2,1   
4,2,1   
4,2,1   
4,2,1   
7,2,9       
3,4,6   
3,4,5
```

sc.size_id is a string with values like => `1,2,3`
I need to join other table and fetch the names based on the above IDs in string.
The table name is sizes, whose values are like

```
id    name
1     2m
2     3m
3     4m
```

I tried this, but can't get the value

```
SELECT sz.name,sc.size_id from subcategories s 
join categories c on c.id = s.categories_id 
join size_categories sc on sc.categories_id = c.id 
join sizes sz on (find_in_set(sz.id,sc.size_id)>0)
```

My size_categories table is

```
id     size_id   categories_id  
1       1,2,5              1    
    
    
    
    
2       9,2,8               2   
    
    
    
    
3      3,4,6               3    
    
    
    
    
4      4,2,1                4
```

I think I need to use group_concat, but it groups everything, so group_by could be better, but how should I use it?
Thank You

Comment: You are using the database incorrectly. `size_categories.size_id` should contain one single `size_id`, as its name suggests. You should even have a foreign key constraint on that column, so as to prevent you from mistakenly inserting something like `'1,2,5'`, which is not an ID. Don't use the workaround suggested in the answer you have accepted. Instead get your data straight. This will help prevent possible issues with the database in the future. Learn how to create a proper database and use it properly. `FIND_IN_SET` is a workaround and should only be used in edge cases. Don't use it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` with a group by on `sc.size_id`

```
select s.name,sc.size_id,group_concat(sz.name)
from subcategories s 
join categories c on c.id = s.categories_id 
join size_categories sc on sc.categories_id = c.id 
join sizes sz on (find_in_set(sz.id,sc.size_id)>0)
group by s.name,sc.size_id
```

If you still get duplicate size names use `distinct` inside `group_concat`

> You should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema DO NOT store relations as comma separated values.

Comment: Thank You for your reply, Sir its reducing the number of rows. total subcategories are 16. the rows returned by this query are 6. every subcategory should have its own sizes name string, as given by category.

Comment: @ShahRukh I have updated my post and included sub category name in select and group by clause